Panicked tree problems
We have a big old walnut tree. We bought landscaping brick and made a flower bed around its trunk. The flowers dies and now we have yellowing leaves dropping off in July. What can we do to save it? We already took the dirt out. Thank you

If the suspense is killing You I have a couple of ideas. 1. Post a macro photo of the portion of the trunk that used to be buried. 2. one cm vertical knife slice on the bark a short distance above that - is it green underneath? Also: welcome to this excellent website!

Either you killed it or you didn't.
If you have restored the soil to the original level that you should not have changed, that's about all you can do but wait to see if it recovers or dies.
